# Application.OnKey event not executing

Tags: excel, vba

Nothing happens when I press "delete" or "backspace".
It should clean the cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TestCell
Dim RE As Object
Dim REMatches As Object
Dim Cell1_1 As String
Dim Today As String

ThisRow = Target.Row

Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", "CleanCell1_1"
Application.OnKey "{BACKSPACE}", "CleanCell1_1"

If Target.Column = 10 Then

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[G,g,Y,y,R,r]"
End With

For Each TestCell In Target.Cells
    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(TestCell.Value)
    If REMatches.Count > 0 Then


    Today = Now()

     Cell1_1 = Sheets("Input").Cells(1, 1).Value
        Range("L" & ThisRow) = Cell1_1 + ": " + Format(Today, "ddmmmyy")
        'MsgBox "Invalid:" & TestCell.Address & "-" & TestCell.Value
        'TestCell.Value = ""

    Else
    MsgBox "Error"
    End If
Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Clarified the question and title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Place the `OnKey` subs in a separate module and call them on `Workbook_Open`. They will take priority over the `Change` event
2. You should disable events when you make changes during a `Change`event - the code will re-call itself

*This Workbook Module*

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.OnKey "{DELETE}"
Application.OnKey "{BACKSPACE}"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "{DELETE}", "CleanCell1_1"
Application.OnKey "{BACKSPACE}", "CleanCell1_1"
End Sub
```

*updated Change code*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TestCell
Dim RE As Object
Dim REMatches As Object
Dim Cell1_1 As String
Dim Today As String
Dim rng1 As Range

ThisRow = Target.Row
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Columns("J"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "[G,g,Y,y,R,r]"
End With

For Each TestCell In rng1.Cells
    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(TestCell.Value)
    If REMatches.Count > 0 Then

        Today = Now()
        Cell1_1 = Sheets("Input").Cells(1, 1).Value
        Range("L" & ThisRow) = Cell1_1 + ": " + Format(Today, "ddmmmyy")
        'MsgBox "Invalid:" & TestCell.Address & "-" & TestCell.Value
        'TestCell.Value = ""
    Else
       MsgBox "Error"
    End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```